# What is the la command?

Tags: command-line, ls

I just mistyped `ls` as `la`. Without noticing, I ran it:

```
tim@Hairy:~$ la
detection.sh   output-2.jpg  output-4.jpg  output-6.jpg  output-8.jpg Test1.pdf
output-1.jpg   output-3.jpg  output-5.jpg  output-7.jpg  output-9.jpg
```

```
tim@Hairy:~$ ls
detection.sh   output-2.jpg  output-4.jpg  output-6.jpg  output-8.jpg Test1.pdf
output-1.jpg   output-3.jpg  output-5.jpg  output-7.jpg  output-9.jpg
```

What's the difference between `ls` and `la`?

Comment: Run `type la`. ;)

Comment: @kos ahh. Nice - so not there for typos?

Comment: Nope. See also `alias | grep '^alias l'`.

Comment: That raised the question that ls is aliased to ls... How?

Comment: Over on [unix.se]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109216/70524

Comment: How come? Because by default `ls` doesn't color its output, so aliasing it to `ls --color=auto` it's a choice of someone (Canonical's developers?) to force `ls` to color the output when connected to a terminal (and I definetly agree with such choice, personally).

Comment: @kos sure, but how does that not create a recursive call?

Comment: Rephrasing it better: "The first word of the replacement text is tested for aliases, but a word that is identical to an alias being expanded is not expanded a second time." (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `.bashrc` file in your home directory, we have these aliases:

```
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
```

`la` is just an alias of `ls` with just the `-A` option.

From `man ls`

```
ls -alF

   -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .

   -l     use a long listing format

   -F, --classify
          append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries


ls -A

   -A, --almost-all
          do not list implied . and ..
```

Answer (score 7):

By default `la` is an alias for `ls -A`. In contrast to just `ls` it doesn't omit files starting with a dot, except for `.` and `..`